# Equation (3.27) from Elements of statistical Learning

Tags: regression, least-squares

It seems the equation below has a typo? Shouldn't $\boldsymbol{y}$ be $\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{1}\bar{y}$?

[image]